# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:amazonathena

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena

I am very new to python and athena.
I am trying to query athena using python.

**code**:

```
import pandas
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

engine = create_engine("amazonathena:///?AccessKey='<key>'&SecretKey='<secretKey>'&Region='IRELAND'&Database='<dbName>'&S3StagingDirectory='s3://<>'")
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT doctype FROM dbName.tableName limit 10;", engine)
print(df)
```

**error** :

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:amazonathena
```

I have also tried `pip install --upgrade amazonathena-sqlalchemy`, but no luck, it says

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement amazonathena-sqlalchemy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for amazonathena-sqlalchemy
```

how to resolve this ? where am  I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/#external-dialects) the external dialect for **Amazon Athena** is [PyAthena](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/#sqlalchemy)

it can be installed via

```bash
pip install PyAthena[SQLAlchemy]
```

> you might need to escape the square brackets:
>
> ```bash
> pip install PyAthena\[SQLAlchemy\]
> ```